# Sql Server join table and merge some rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are three tables as below: A for tower info, B for defender info and C for their relations

```
TableA:
TowerID  TowerName  DefenderName
1        TwA        DefA
2        TwB        DefB
3        TwC        DefA,DefB

TableB:
DefenderID  DefenderName
1           DefA
2           DefB

TableC:
TowerID  DefenderID
1        1
2        2
3        1
3        2
```

And I use the following sql statement to join them:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TableA.TowerID,TableA.TowerName,TableA.DefenderName,TableC.DefenderID
FROM TableA,TableC
WHERE TableA.TowerID = TableC.TowerID) AS tbl

TowerID  TowerName  DefenderName  DefenderID
1        TwA        DefA          1
2        TwB        DefB          2
3        TwC        DefA,DefB     1
3        TwC        DefA,DefB     2
```

If DefA login, I can append that statement with:

```
WHERE DefenderID = 1
```

and he will see

```
TowerID  TowerName  DefenderName  DefenderID
1        TwA        DefA          1
3        TwC        DefA,DefB     1
```

If DefB login, DefenderID = 2.

If the King login, I want to show him something like:

```
TowerID  TowerName  DefenderName
1        TwA        DefA
2        TwB        DefB
3        TwC        DefA,DefB
```

How can I modify the sql statement to show the King the table above, and when DefA or DefB login all I need to do is to append the sql with a "WHERE DefenderID = 'x' " and they will only see their own info?

(column DefenderID is not  necessary)

Comment: Look up parameterized stored procedures.

Comment: Who is `King login` ?

Comment: "King" is the admin who can see all

Comment: The King query should be `SELECT * From TableA`, You should have two separated querys.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT   --- include this
               tablea.towerid, 
               tablea.towername, 
               tablea.defendername, 
               tablec.defenderid 
        FROM   tablea, 
               tablec 
        WHERE  tablea.towerid = tablec.towerid) AS tbl
```

Comment: tbl still has two rows whose towerid is 3, one row's defenderid is 1,another is 2 when I include the "DISTINCT". Is there a way to merge them?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are working with a dynamic query if you want to tack on the where clause.  It can get more sophisticated if you have a user table that matches the login of the session but for now this should work:

```
Declare @Sql Varchar(8000)
Set @Sql = 
'SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TableA.TowerID,TableA.TowerName,TableA.DefenderName
FROM TableA,TableC
GROUP BY TowerID, TowerName, DefenderName
WHERE TableA.TowerID = TableC.TowerID) AS tbl'

If @User = 'DefA'
  Set @Sql = @Sql + ' Where DefenderID = 1'
Else If @User = 'DefB'
  Set @Sql = @Sql + ' Where DefenderID = 2 '
Else If @User = 'King'
  Set @Sql = @Sql + ' Where 1 = 1 '
Else 
  Set @Sql = 'Error handling goes here, for now query will error instead '

Exec (@Sql)
```

Here I set `@Sql = @Sql + 'Where 1=1'`,  just a blank string would work as well `@Sql = @Sql + ' '`

Comment: What about the King? He can see all towers

Comment: Anyone who is not defined as a user is the 'King'.  I will edit to explicitly reference him.

Comment: The problem is you will get the row `3        TwC        DefA,DefB` twice. And that isnt the OP desire output

Comment: I didnt see that, thank you.  A group by or distinct takes care of that.  Since Defender ID is not needed we can just leave it out.  Answer updated.